# Is it possible to use require.js on a dynamically built page with iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, requirejs

So I'm working with an iframe in page that is dynamically built with jQuery elements. I want to load several external javascript files in a specific order inside that iFrame. Is it possible to load require.js in that iFrame and then use it to load the external js files through the js code?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm dealing with a similar problem right now. Appending require.js to the iframe contents doesn't seem to work `$iframe.contents().find("head").append($("<script>", {"data-main": "admin/app", src: "/admin/javascripts/require.js"}));`

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests and finally got it working like this:

Select iframe head

```
$iframe = $('#target'),
$head = $iframe.contents().find("head");
```

Add require to iframe

```
$head.append($("<script>", {src: "/path_to/require.js"}));
```

For some reason `data-main` attribute was being ignored so I had to turn on the config myself

```
var startRequire = (function() {/**
                        requirejs.config({
                            "baseUrl": "/your/path",
                             //more config
                        });
                        // Load the main app module to start the app
                        requirejs(["/your/path/main.js"]);
                    **/})
                   .toString().split('\n').slice(1, -1).join('\n'); //this hack is here just so I don't keep adding plusses and "'", configs can get complex
$head.append($('<script>').html(startRequire))
```

Keep in mind that when adding .js from parent to iframe, the current scope of the loaded script(s) will still be the parent so if you're using jQuery in `main.js` you would have to declare the scope:

```
var iframe = $('#target')[0].contentWindow.document; //iframe
$('.selected', iframe); //look for element with class selected within the iframe
```